# AJAX call back to download file by browser

Tags: java, ajax

When user clicks the button, there is ajax calls to server. The server returns a text file.
I would like browser to download the file automatically.

```
.jsp button
<button type="submit" id="btn_load" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary">Generate I-618</button>

.js file - when button is click 
$("#btn_load").click(function(e) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            form = $('#bookList');
            var post_url = form.attr("action"); 
            let form_data = form.serialize();  
             $.ajax({
                url: post_url,
                type: "POST",
                data: form_data,
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqX) {
                    // **data is a .txt file. HOW TO TELL BROWSER TO DOWNLOAD THE .TXT FILE ?**
                    console.log(data); //print the data from the file
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus,  errorThrown) {
                }
            });
    });
});
```

java: function returns a .text file that would like to download from browser when user click the button

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/book.htm")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> bookselection(
        @ModelAttribute("books") Books book, Model model,
        HttpServletRequest request, BindingResult result) {
    List<InputStreamResource> listStream = new ArrayList<InputStreamResource>();
    String fileName = "book.txt"
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(bookList)) {
        File file = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".txt");
        FileWriter interfaceFileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter interfaceBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(interfaceFileWriter);
        //write to file
        for (Book list : bookList) {
        interfaceBufferedWriter.write(list.getDelimitedRecord(delimiter, nullValue));
        }
        interfaceBufferedWriter.close();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData(fileName + ".txt", fileName + ".txt");

        InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
        if (file != null && file.exists()) {
            listStream.add(resource);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).headers(headers).body(resource);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

How to tell browser to download the file automatically which is ajax response (data)?

Comment: how about opening the url using `window.open` while the server giving `application/octet-stream` as mime type?